# create a menu on mouseover the customer name in jsp page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have to design a menu on mouse over the customer name,and if mouse is placed at that customer menu shows details of customer fetch from database.
Like,
Name of customer
qwerty <-when mouse placed on this it shows its region,email-id
ytrew

Comment: what you had tried so far? yes can do this using ajax.

Comment: actually i am new with this and my customer name come from database and link is create on this,how can i assign id to that.